# Source Image React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-native

I want to ask ask you all. I want to display image from local asset but for filename from object response api. I have tried some code but can't work. Do you everyone help me?
below is some code that I have tried. I also added image to mylocal and my object response api already the same name with extension

```
<Image
   source={`../../../asset/images/Topup/${props.image}`}
   style={styles.GridImage}
   resizeMode="contain"
/>
```

```
<Image
   source={'../../../asset/images/Topup/' + ${props.image}}
   style={styles.GridImage}
   resizeMode="contain"
/>
```

```
<Image
   source={require(`../../../asset/images/Topup/${props.image}`)}
   style={styles.GridImage}
   resizeMode="contain"
/>
```

```
<Image
   source={require('../../../asset/images/Topup/' + ${props.image})}
   style={styles.GridImage}
   resizeMode="contain"
/>
```

Comment: Does the `props.image` value match an image inside your `assets/images/Topup` folder?

Comment: yes, I have added an image in my assets @Moistbobo

Comment: Does `props.image` also include the extension? eg .png, .jpg, etc

Comment: Yes, this is example {"flagBadge": "PR", "id": "1", "imageFav": "phone.png", "image": "sa_topup_pulsa.png", "keyword": "topPhone", "nameEN": "Phone Top Up", "nameIN": "Pulsa", "payeeCategory": "17", "payeeId": "32"} @Moistbobo

Comment: Thanks for including it, but could you also edit your question to include it? It's a little difficult to read as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

pass image as prop like this
`props.image` will equal `require('fullpath/to/image-without-variables')`
use it like this
`<Image source={props.image} .../>`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use variables when requiring an image. The argument passed to require must be a string literal. Try `require('../../../asset/images/Topup/image_name.extension')`.

Answer (score -1):

**Try to copy the path of the image and paste it**

or

you can import the image to the value after that write the value in the source

```
import value from 'path your image';


<Image
   source={value}
   style={styles.GridImage}
   resizeMode="contain"
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).